# Django can't click the button

Tags: jquery, django

this is jquery

```
{% block custom_js %}
    <script>
            $(function() {
            $('#jsStayBtn').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: {% url 'org:add_ask' %},
                    data: $('#jsStayForm').serialize(),
                    async:true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        alert(data)
                        if(data.status == 'success') {
                            $('#jsStayForm')[0].reset();
                            alert('successful')
                        }
                        else if(data.status == 'fail') {
                            $('#jsCompanyTips').html(data.msg)
                        }
                    },
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

this is submit html

```html
 <div class="right companyright">
   <div class="head">Studing</div>
   <form class="rightform" id="jsStayForm">
    <div>
                    <img src="{% static 'images/rightform1.png' %}"/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="companyName" placeholder="name" maxlength="25" />
                </div>
    <div>
                    <img src="{% static 'images/rightform2.png' %}"/>
                    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="companyMobile" placeholder="mobile"/>
                </div>
    <div>
                    <img src="{% static 'images/rightform3.png' %}"/>
                    <input type="text" name="course_name" id="companyAddress" placeholder="course_name" maxlength="50" />
                </div>
                <p class="error company-tips" id="jsCompanyTips"></p>
                <input class="btn" type="text" id="jsStayBtn" value="consult >" />

            {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
  </div>
```

this is urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    # 课程机构列表页
    url('^list/$', OrgView.as_view(), name="org_list"),
    url('^add_ask/$',AddUserAskView.as_view(), name='add_ask'),
]
```

There is an input box on the page, which is ajax and is implemented through jquery.But when I'm done, I don't have any reaction to the click of the button, I don't know what went wrong.This should be a POST request,How should I modify the normal submission?

Comment: When you debug in your browser, is there any error on the debugging console?  Is the click handler invoked at all?  Is the AJAX request made?  Is it what you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: there might be one issue of html structure try with just form tag and remove div.
i need to check it but let me know after doing it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#jsStayBtn',function(){

   //ajax function 

});
```

Sometimes compiler will not found the class/id. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

my bad.Because I didn't use jquery, I made a small mistake in using django for the first time.It should be written like this:

```
url:"{% url 'org:add_ask' %}",
```